# how to make empty set using p=set()

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create an empty set. but it's not working it is throwing an error

```
p = set()
```

error:
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: looks like you have used `set` as a variable in your code

Comment: thanks a lot ... it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've named a variable `set` elsewhere in your code, which has removed `set` from the namespace and the interpreter now thinks that it is a dictionary, not a function. It is the equivalent of

```
foo = "hello"
bar = foo()
```

which will of course error because foo is not a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot/... it helped